# Kohana 3.2 Validation_Exception will not support errors()

Tags: validation, exception, kohana-3, php

I am trying to add the error messages to my validation object.

It says that errors is not a method of Validation_Exception. That I know... The thing is that I though the $e variable would be the instance of the Validation Class in the model. My question is how can attach the error messages?

Error:

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Validation_Exception::errors()

Controller:

```
208             // redirect to the user account
209             $this->request->redirect('user/profile');
210          } catch (Validation_Exception $e) {
211             // Get errors for display in view
212             // Note how the first param is the path to the message file (e.g. /messages/register.php)
213             $errors = $e->errors('register/user');
214             // Move external errors to main array, for post helper compatibility
215             $errors = array_merge($errors, (isset($errors['_external']) ? $errors['_external'] : array()));
216             $view->set('errors', $errors);
217             // Pass on the old form values
218             $_POST['password'] = $_POST['password_confirm'] = '';
```

Model:

```
$validation = Validation::factory($fields)
                    ->rules('username', $this->_rules['username'])
                    ->rule('username', array($this, 'username_available'), array(':validation', ':field'))
                    ->rules('email', $this->_rules['email'])
                    ->rule('email', array($this, 'email_available'), array(':validation', ':field'))
                    ->rules('password', $this->_rules['password'])
                    ->rules('password_confirm', $this->_rules['password_confirm']);
                    //->labels($_labels);

            if (Kohana::config('useradmin')->activation_code) {
                    $validation->rule('activation_code', array($this, 'check_activation_code'), array(':validation', ':field'));
            }

            if(!$validation->check())
            {
                    throw new Validation_Exception($validation, __('Your registering information is not valid.'));
            }
```

I really don't see why this error is accuring.

Comment: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically answered your own question - `Validation_Exception` doesn't have `errors` method. You need to call it from `Validation` object instead.

Comment: So what can I throw as an Exception?